# Dynamic Canvas DrawImage Function

Tags: javascript, dynamic, canvas, drawimage

I've got a problem filling 25 canvas elements automatically in a for loop. They are numbered like so: `can01` to `can25`.

I've tried all I knew to draw different images on the canvas and I have spent a lot of time in searching a few articles which are about this problem but I haven't found any.

This is my working code to fill all canvas elements with the same image:

```
var imageGrass = new Image();       

imageGrass.src = 'recources/imagesBG/grass.jpg';

imageGrass.onload = function() {
    for (var i = 1; i < 26; i++)
    {
        if( i < 10 )
        {
            var task = "can0" + i + "_ctx.drawImage(imageGrass, 0, 0);";
            eval(task);
        }
        else
        {
            var task = "can" + i + "_ctx.drawImage(imageGrass, 0, 0);";
            eval(task);
        }
    }
}
```

But I really don't know how to make the `imageGrass.src` dynamic. For example, the canvas element no. 5 (can05) in this case shall look like stone texture.

I´m really looking forward to read your ideas. I just don't get it.

Comment: This is a prime example of "eval is evil". Reformat your code so that it doesn't use `eval` and you'll find this *much* easier.

Comment: hint: `window['name']` == `name`, but you could also use an array (which would be better)

Answer (score 3):

**Here’s how to impliment Dave’s good idea of using arrays to organize your canvases:**

Create an array that will hold references to all your 25 canvases (do the same for 25 contexts)

```
var canvases=[];
var contexts=[];
```

Next, fill the array with all your canvases and contexts:

```
for(var i=0;i<25;i++){
    var canvas=document.getElementById("can"+(i<10?"0":""));
    var context=canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvases[i]=canvas;
    contexts[i]=context;
}
```

If you haven't seen it before:  `i<10?"0":""` is an inline if/else used here to add a leading zero to your lower-numbered canvases.

Then you can fetch your “can05” canvas like this:

```
var canvas=canvases[4];
```

Why 4 and not 5?    Arrays are zero based, so canvases[0] holds can01.  Therefore array element 4 contains your 5th canvas “can05”.

So you can fetch the drawing context for your “can05” like this:

```
var context=contexts[4];
```

As Dave says, “evals are evil” so here’s how to fetch the context for “can05” and draw the stone image on it.

```
var context=contexts[4];
context.drawImage(stoneImage,0,0);
```

This stone drawing can be shortened to:

```
contexts[4].drawImage(stoneImage,0,0);
```

You can even put this shortened code into a function for easy reuse and modification:

```
function reImage( canvasIndex, newImage ){
    contexts[ canvasIndex ].drawImage( newImage,0,0 );
}
```

Then you can change the image on any of your canvases by calling the function:

```
reimage( 4,stoneImage );
```

That’s it!

The evil-evals have been vanquished  (warning: never invite them to your computer again!)

Here is example code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/ZuU2e/

This code creates 25 canvases dynamically rather than hard-coding 25 html canvas elements.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; padding:0px; margin:0px;border:0px; }
    canvas{vertical-align: top; }
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvases=[];
    var contexts=[];

    var grass=new Image();
    grass.onload=function(){

        // the grass is loaded
        // now make 25 canvases and fill them with grass
        // ALSO !!!
        // keep track of them in an array
        // so we can use them later!
        make25CanvasesFilledWithGrass()    

        // just a test
        // fill canvas#3 with gold
        draw(3,"gold");
        // fill canvas#14 with red
        draw(14,"red");

    }
    //grass.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/grass.jpg";
    //grass.src="grass.jpg";

    function make25CanvasesFilledWithGrass(){

        // get the div that we will fill with 25 canvases
        var container=document.getElementById("canvasContainer");

        for(var i=0;i<25;i++){
            // create a new html canvas element
            var canvas=document.createElement("canvas");
            // assign the new canvas an id, width and height
            canvas.id="can"+(i<10?"0":"")+i;
            canvas.width=grass.width;
            canvas.height=grass.height;
            // get the context for this new canvas
            var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
            // draw the grass image in the new canvas
            ctx.drawImage(grass,0,0);
            // add this new canvas to the web page
            container.appendChild(canvas);
            // add this new canvas to the canvases array
            canvases[i]=canvas;
            // add the context for this new canvas to the contexts array
            contexts[i]=ctx;
        }  

    }

    // test -- just fill the specified canvas with the specified color
    function draw(canvasIndex,newColor){
        var canvas=canvases[canvasIndex];
        var ctx=contexts[canvasIndex];
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle=newColor;
        ctx.rect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ctx.fill();
    }


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="canvasContainer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```